# How to enable LAN Hostname resolution

Tags: networking, iot, hostname

I am developing a home automation application using IoT components.  Most of these SOC's implement a web page for configuration and control, and I would like to be able to access these pages using the hostname vs. IP address.

Problem is some devices are accessible vis hostname and others are not.  A port scan of my LAN shows some devices have host names and some don't.  The ones with host names are accessible using the name, the others are not.  All are WiFi connected using DHCP.  The router is a generic WiFi router, with DHCP.

Since this is working on some devices I'm assuming that the infrastructure that makes this work is Ok, and the failure is on the part of the host when it registers itself on the network.  So the question is, how does a host make it's name known to the network?  Is it part of the WiFi connection protocol, DHCP, or what?

The objective is to fix the failing devices to properly register themselves on the network.  I have source code for everything, so hopefully this is doable.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) site? I think it might be a better fit than Stack Overflow, because you're more interested in the networking architecture than an actual code issue.

Comment: I figured since I have the source code and the solution is probably to fix it that it was a programming question.  I will post on the IoT site though, just in case.  Thanks.